# Hibernate criterion that matches against everything in some cases

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

is it possible to do something like

```
criteria.add(Expression.eq("product", " * "))
```

for it to match everything ?

It would be handy in case that you get a variable that can have many values and a special value "all" that matches against everything. So you can call a method like this and if the variable had a value of "all", then the expression would match everything.

```
public void someFunction(String variable) {

    criteria.add(Expression.eq("product", variable))  

}
```

EDITED: If I had 2 select fields with Source Language & Destination Language and a table listing entries based on which language combination it contains, with IF STATEMENTS it would look like this: (DynamicQuery is an abstraction for Criteria)

```
private DynamicQuery addCriteria(DynamicQuery dq, String languageFrom, String languageTo){

    if (null != languageFrom && !languageFrom.isEmpty() && null != languageTo && !languageTo.isEmpty()){

        if(languageFrom.equals("All") && languageTo.equals("All")) {
            return dq;
        } else if (!languageFrom.equals("All") && !languageTo.equals("All")) {
            dq.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("languageFrom").eq(languageFrom));
            dq.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("languageTo").eq(languageTo));    
            return dq;
        } else if (languageFrom.equals("All") && !languageTo.equals("All")) {
            dq.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("languageTo").eq(languageTo));   
            return dq;
        } else if (!languageFrom.equals("All") && languageTo.equals("All")) {
            dq.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("languageFrom").eq(languageFrom)); 
            return dq;
        } 
    } 
}
```

It's disgusting, consider there would be one more field, it would be even more disgusting...One simply must cover all the combinations that might occur ... That's why I would like to have something like REGEX, because I would assign variable the reqex "*" value and I would add two lines like this

```
dq.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("languageFrom").eq(languageFromVariable));
dq.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("languageTo").eq(languageToVariable));
```

Comment: If you want everything why are you adding criteria?

Comment: @fatih, only in some cases...imagine that you have a select field in a form and there is [all, red, blue, green, yellow] ... and based on what user selects, it will list something... I'm new to hibernate and I can't find an alternative in documentation

Comment: Without this, I'd have to create a condition : if ( variable == "all") { create completely different criteria than if it is not }

Comment: an if statement is the correct way of doing it. Why you dont want to add an if stmt?

Comment: There's nothing what equals to everything in SQL and therefore in Hibernate either. You can use something strange like the equivalent of `product==variable || variable==""` but this may lead to slower execution. Conditionally leaving out the condition is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (null != variable && !variable.isEmpty()){
    criteria.add(Expression.eq("product", variable)) ;
}
```

If you only need it when it is selected. You may wanna add an if statement so criteria is added only when needed.

Edit 1:

You can define a method if you are gonna use it for more than fields. Even you can define different criterias inside here. Easy maintance (as is used by all and centrilized), code reuse (change at one point at it will be effective to all)

```
addCriteria(Criteria criteria, String name, String value){

 //you wanna handle special cases like null == name as well accordingly

    if (null != value && !value.isEmpty() && null != name && !name.isEmpty()){
        criteria.add(Expression.eq(name, value)) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to avoid to ... because if it is a much more complicated case then this one, the feature I'm looking for would make things more transparent and maintainable ...

Comment: Consider that you have 3 select fields in html form, and all of them have the "all" option, then you'd have to take care of all the combinations by if stmts

Comment: [object.field1 = all, object.field2 = blue, object.field3 = red]  this is one combination from 9

Comment: @lisak see above edit; for several similar fields you can use centrilized methods to do the logic of adding criteria.

Comment: Why not call call above addCriteria method twice ? You need 1 if/else for this case. Dont merge all possible logic paths into one method.  addCriteria(criteria,"fromLanguage",fromLanguageValue); addCriteria(criteria,"toLanguage",toLanguageValue);

Comment: Omg you're right, what was I thinking :-) I'm too tired, thank you fatih